# How do i remove "default"?

Tags: json, python-3.x, mapping, tinydb

i have been having some problems understanding where i went wrong in my codes. I have been trying to print out the output of my codes into a json file but apparently, my list is empty because it has this "default" thing printed out. How do i change it such that the books map has Book Id and Serial no. part into the empty {} instead? I already did my own research but unfortunately none of the forums that i went to provided an answer.

Here's my output:

```
{"books": {}, "_default":
  {
   "1": {Book ID: XXXX bookid 1 XXXX},
   "2": {Serial No.: XXX serialno 1 XXXX}
  },
 {
   "1": {Book ID: XXX bookid 2 XXXX},
   "2": {Serial No.: XXX serial no. 2 XXX}
 }
}
```

Here are my codes:

```
with open("/home/pi/Desktop/json/pillar1.json", 'w+'):
        db = TinyDB('/home/pi/Desktop/json/pillar1.json')
        table = db.table('Books')
        db.insert_multiple([{'Book ID' : variable}, {'Serial no' : variable]}])
```

Comment: this looks an awefull lot like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44384527/how-do-i-print-it-into-an-organised-json-file) which already has an answer, so I suggest that you continue working there... and (!!) it looks also like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44361149/how-do-i-print-a-list-in-json-file-using-tinydb) ... or you could update this question, and state that previous posts have not received any workable answers.

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo hi, thanks for the reply. but believe it or not, they are both my accounts. The one with the reply, did not answer the qn at all. and the one without, i tried to delete but it gave a pop-up saying that i might be kicked out if i deleted another question :')

Comment: I noticed that you were trying to edit my answer with your update. I rejected that edit. please use comment section if you have an update/comment on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is always a `_default` table, described [here](http://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#default-table)

Operations like `db.insert_multiple` will happen on the `_default` table.
Which you actually show in your file sniplet correctly.

Table `"books"` is empty

```
"books": {}
```

and the `inserts` have take place on the `_default` table

```
"_default":
  {
   "1": {Book ID: XXXX bookid 1 XXXX},
   "2": {Serial No.: XXX serialno 1 XXXX}
  },
 {
   "1": {Book ID: XXX bookid 2 XXXX},
   "2": {Serial No.: XXX serial no. 2 XXX}
 }
```

In order to insert in a table, you can do the following:

```
with open("/home/pi/Desktop/json/pillar1.json", 'w+'):
        db = TinyDB('/home/pi/Desktop/json/pillar1.json')
        table = db.table('books')
        table.insert_multiple([{'Book ID' : variable}, {'Serial no' : variable]}])
```

note the `table.insert_multiple` in stead of `db.insert_multiple`

[EDIT]

you can set your own default table as described [here](http://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#default-table)